# Datastax - Cassandra php-driver: Uncaught Cassandra\Exception\LogicException:

Tags: php, cassandra, datastax

I'm on Ubuntu right now trying to connect to Cassandra with PHP. I have installed Datastax php-driver and all of its dependencies but i get this error when trying to run a testfile:

```
    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Cassandra\Exception\LogicException: Not    implemented in /home/philip/Documents/test.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 /home/user/Documents/test.php(3): Cassandra\Cluster\Builder->build()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/user/Documents/test.php on line 3
```

The code looks like this:

```
 <?php
// Connect to the cluster and keyspace "killrvideo"
$cluster  = Cassandra::cluster()->build();
$keyspace  = 'killrvideo';
$session  = $cluster->connect($keyspace);
```

I manage to connect to cassandra using the shell cqlsh and i can see the table i have setup. The php code doesnt seem to work though. Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you pulled the driver from git? I think some of the last commit might be broken since I have the same problem as you but using the commit f50c93d  (this commit is from Nov 22) works without problem

Comment: https://github.com/datastax/php-driver/commits/master

Comment: Using the commit from Nov 22 worked perfectly, thanks a lot @AlexandruCircus!

Answer (score 3):

We have the same issue. This works for me.
Thanks a lot @AlexandruCircus!

```
git clone https://github.com/datastax/php-driver.git
git reset --hard f50c93da3ea73ad8fcf8b181d0313d437e559256
cd php-driver/ext
./install.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

well this is not very clear for me but you call this from the same server ?
witch strategy you use ? simples or network topology  ?
but something that I'm sure will work with this

$cluster  = Cassandra::cluster()->withContactPoints('127.0.0.1')->build();

// or if you call from a different server just replace the ip